How to extend authorization to other related projects in ASP.NET Core MVC?
How to make related projects protected by one authorization in ASP.NET Core MVC project? Centralized authentication and authorization system. Without the participation of third-party applications.
The simplest example. Thank you very much in advance.
Program.cs (identity project)
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

// ...

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

AccountController (identity project)
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;

    public AccountController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }

    // ...
}

Program.cs (other project)
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

// ...

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

HomeController (other project)
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}

enter image description here

Configure a shared cookie with the same name, encryption keys across all applications. ASP.NET Core Identity in one project should issue the cookie, and other projects should accept the same cookie for authentication.
Program.cs(Identity Project):
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();


// Configure cookie authentication for shared cookie
builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\PATH TO COMMON KEY RING FOLDER"))
    .SetApplicationName("SharedCookieApp");

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
    options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNet.SharedCookie";
});

var app = builder.Build();    
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();

Program.cs(other project):
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication("Identity.Application") // Identity cookie scheme
    .AddCookie("Identity.Application", options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNet.SharedCookie";   // Must match the identity project's cookie name
    });
builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\PATH TO COMMON KEY RING FOLDER"))
    .SetApplicationName("SharedCookieApp");
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();

Reference: Share authentication cookies among ASP.NET apps
